# Calculate the hazard rate of the Rayleigh distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The Rayleigh distribution is a continuous distribution with one parameter, $\sigma^2$. The pdf of the Rayleigh distribution is:

f(x)=($\frac{x}{\sigma^2} )$e^$(\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2})$, for x$\ge$0

f(x)=0, for x<0

Calculate the hazard rate of the Rayleigh distribution. Is the Rayleigh distribution heavy or light-tailed?

I have no idea how to start with it, do I find the survival function first? But I don't know how to do that. Please Help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a difficult problem if you know the definition of the hazard function $f(x)/R(x)$, where the survival function $R(x) = 1 - F(x).$
So you are correct that you need to find the survival function (also called
reliability function) and then you are almost finished.

If you need to check your answer for the cumulative distribution function $F(x),$ look at Wikipedia for 'Rayleigh distribution'.
The messy parts cancel and you might be surprised how simple the hazard rate function is.

Comment: Thanks for the help, then how can I determine whether it is heavy or light tailed?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no standard definition of the difference between heavy and light tailed. Maybe in reliability theory it heavier or lighter than exponential, or new better or worse than used, or hazard function decreasing or increasing. A pure guess is that Rayleigh is probably considered 'heavy' tailed. If you have a definition of heavy tailed, maybe we can figure it out.